# Selenium/Phantomjs: how to tell if a navigation is made?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I tried using Selenium/PhantomJS/Python to write a scraper. I use the 'get' method to open an URL, with a few seconds as page loading time-out.

But sometimes I found that the 'get' method doesn't open the URL. As a result, when I parse the web page, I get the same result as the previous scrape.

In this case, I need to tell when I open an URL, whether the page have navigated or stayed in the same page. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the new page has a different URL, you can check the [attribute `current_url`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=current_url) on your browser/driver.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to know more about this. At which point is this attribute current_url set to the new URL? When it starts receiving response from the server, or after the page is fully loaded? This would be helpful to know in slow network environment.

Comment: For many pages that rely on javascript there is no such thing as a page being "fully loaded".  For me (but I only scraped a million or two different pages with my programs), this was never relevant. But you should not post new questions (even related) as a comment to an answer. If at all post a new question, **describe what you tried**, and why you cannot determine your answer yourself with your efforts. That is how this site works. Don't try to use the comments as some forum substitute.

Comment: Anthon, thanks for the answer. Here is the usage of comments described in the Tour page of this website: "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer." My question was meant to get clarification of your answer so I consider it appropriate. I will try your suggestion and come back. Thanks.